# How to prevent loss of event retrieval while reading from event log?

Tags: c#, winapi, event-log, system.diagnostics

I'm using [EventLogWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2) class (as it was suggested as the fastest available method to read from event log) to read newly written events. Let's say I have an event-log named `CustomEventLog1` of size 2MB. I have an application to write a total of 20000 events to this log and have set `Overwrite events as needed` when the log reaches maximum size.

Now, as I start writing the events, the watcher obviously lags reading speed and events get lost.

Let me tell how it happens; when the application is writing say `(1000th entry)`, the watcher is still reading the `500th entry` so when the watcher comes to read the`2000th entry`, the writing application has already replaced it with the `4000th entry`.

So after `1999th entry`, I get `4000th entry`. When the application completed writing `20000 events`, the watcher only got `12020 entries` and the remaining were lost.

Is there any way to work around this? I know increasing the log file size will just do it, but is there any way to achieve this without increasing the log size and without reducing the writing speed.

Comment: Presumably there is overhead in the notification process. I would say once you get a "change" notification you should read all new events in a loop before restarting the notification system.

Comment: The problem is my application writes 10000 events per second to an event log and the event log watcher can only read 3000 or maybe less events per second @jonathan

Comment: At the moment you're reading one event at a time, waiting for a notification callback before you read the next one. What I'm suggesting is, read *all* new notification events in a loop once you get notification of the first one. Or change your application to not spam the event log with a ridiculous number of events in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You want to do the Overwriting without increasing the log size and reducing the writing speed, And you also want to read the log which has been overwriting, You can't have both. But you can set `logsize >= 20000`, and delete the event after it has been read, so that the log size will be saved to the greatest extent.